About uncertainty and the range of the nuclear interaction
When we calculate the mass of a pion, if let's say the range of nuclear interaction is 1 femtometer, we say
$1\ \mathrm{fm}=c \Delta t$
First question is, why do we write here $\Delta t$, how is lifetime of a meson equals to uncertainty in time?
Then what we do is find $\Delta t$ and put it in Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle to get $\Delta E$, and then we write  $\Delta E=m_pc^2$,
Here also how do we write this because shouldn't it be $E=m_pc^2$ ?
In short I am unable to understand why do we use uncertainty in something and its value itself simultaneously.

I think that you may have muddled a question about the range of the nuclear interaction and other Yukawa-potential interactions with a similar-sounding-but-quite-different question about the "energy width" of an excited state and its lifetime. Can you clarify which is more important? The answer I started sort of spiraled out of control trying to address both.

I am not quite sure, what is yukawa potential interaction, but there was a question in my assignment about finding mass of pion, given the range of nuclear interaction, and I couldn't really understand how do we use uncertainty in this way.

I just looked up energy width problem of yukawa potential, my question is about range of the nuclear interaction

Range of Yukawa potential: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/810121

Let's try to come up with this argument about the pion mass without making any assumptions that you don't like.  We'll start with the fact that nucleons are confined within the nucleus. That means that the uncertainty in a nucleon's position is
$$
\sigma_x \approx 1\text{ fm}
$$
and therefore the uncertainty in its momentum is
$$
\sigma_p \approx \frac{\hbar}{\sigma_x}.
$$
Now, we can always choose a coordinate system where the mean momentum is zero.  But this is different from a system where the momentum is zero, because our nonzero uncertainty $\sigma_p \neq 0$ means that we don't know the momentum. In particular, that uncertainty tells us that the scale of the nonzero momenta that the nucleons have within the nucleus, as they scatter around and interact with each other. This scale is called the "root-mean-square" momentum, $\sigma_p = \sqrt{\left< p^2 \right>}$.
That's the fundamental answer to the question in your final line.  If you have a quantity whose mean value is zero, the uncertainty in the quantity is a good estimator for its typical value.
The range parameter goes like $\sigma_x \sim {\hbar c}/{mc^2}$, which is the Compton wavelength of the particle associated with the field which mediates the interaction.  There are two levels of explanation for this connection, but I'm not sure that either will satisfy you. The low-level hand-waving explanation is dimensional analysis: the mass of the field which mediates an interaction is really the only parameter available which can be related to a length by dimensional analysis. The high-level explanation has to do with the Fourier transform of the propagator $({p^2 + m^2})^{-1}$. There's an version of the argument in the Wikipedia article on the Yukawa potential, and another version in this answer to a related question.
